How can I align the object's or 3d cursor X, Y and Z-axis to tracking together with face normal

bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler = Vector((0,0,1)).rotation_difference(bpy.context.object.data.polygons[bpy.context.object.data.polygons.active].normal).to_euler()
bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler = bpy.context.object.data.polygons[bpy.context.object.data.polygons.active].normal.to_track_quat('Z').to_euler()


Can you tell us what exactly you're doing and what you're hoping to achieve?
